# Positioning in Django Template by Models Field

Tags: django, html, django-templates

Hello i want to put my players in html according to their positions from my model like if one players position field is added as "striker" in model i want to put them in div with "Strikers" class. How can i do that?

here is my models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
position = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Position")
player_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Player")
player_age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Player Age")
```

And here is my html;

```
<div class="Strikers"></div>

<div class="Midfielders"></div>
```

And here is my views.py;

```
def player_index(request):
players = Player.objects.all()
return render(request, "players/index.html", {'players': players})
```

Thanks so much in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your template like this:

```
{% for player in players %}

    {% if player.position == 'striker' %}
    <div class="Strikers">
    # Put your content here
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if player.position == 'midfielder' %}
    <div class="Midfielders">
    # Put your content here
    </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Make sure that you have same `value` for position in database, what you are checking in `if` condition.

It will work.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. And for my case this solution is better than the previous one ( changing views.py) because i have many fields so it will take too much time to change every function.. Thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

Better to separate your players in views itself.

```
def player_index(request):
   strikers = Player.objects.filter(position='striker')
   midfielders = Player.objects.filter(position='midfielder')
   return render(request, "players/index.html", {'strikers': strikers, 'midfielders':midfielders})
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.. As i commented for other answer (the one with changing the html) that one better way for my case. Because i have many fields and functions and it will take too much time for me at the moment. But i guess if i have had planned the structure this way before, this way would be very efficient. Thank you very much again.